# Finding the Basis for an Orthogonal Subspace

Tags: vectors

[image: Image Link]

The above link is the image of the question. How do you find the basis for the orthogonal complement of a subspace given the subspace and its basis? We have not learned gram-schmidt yet in class.

Comment: Hint 1: Gram-Schmidt. Hint 2: the null space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its row space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $W$ be a given subspace of $V$ find the orthogonal complement $W^{\perp}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828661/let-w-be-a-given-subspace-of-v-find-the-orthogonal-complement-w-perp) and many others.